# Laravel composer and package discover

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan

In a new project after cloned it and run composer install I have:

```
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover


[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 
'cryptoreview.out  
going_links' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `outgoing_links`)             



[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]                                          
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 
'cryptoreview.out  
going_links' doesn't exist                                                   



[PDOException]                                                               
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 
'cryptoreview.out  
going_links' doesn't exist
```

what exactly is trying to do package:discover?

I tried to fix running php artisan migrate but:

```
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'cryptoreview.outgoing_links' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `outgoing_links`)
```

It is a complete blocked situation. No way to proceed further

Comment: Laravel 5.5 introduced Package discovery to automatically register package service providers. Not sure why it's attempting to hit the database, but it looks like an issue with your migrations perhaps? What happens if you try to run a `php artisan migrate:fresh`? (note the `:fresh`)

Comment: Running `migrate:fresh` will delete all data from db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `composer global update` in your terminal to update your composer. And for base table not found, make sure your table migration is Schema::create not Schema::table. Don't forget function up and down with the same name of table.